# Freezing TensorFlow2 layers

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I have a LeNet-300-100 dense neural network for MNIST dataset where I want to freeze the first two layers having 300 and 100 hidden neurons in the first two hidden layers. I just want to train the output layer. The code I have to do this is as follows:

```
from tensorflow import keras

inner_model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.Input(shape=(1024,)),
        keras.layers.Dense(300, activation="relu", kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.GlorotNormal()),
        keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu", kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.GlorotNormal()),
    ]
)

model_mnist = keras.Sequential(
    [keras.Input(shape=(1024,)), inner_model, keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"),]
)

# model_mnist.trainable = True  # Freeze the outer model
# Freeze the inner model-
inner_model.trainable = False


# Sanity check-
inner_model.trainable, model_mnist.trainable
# (False, True)

# Compile NN-
model_mnist.compile(
    loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
    # optimizer='adam',
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr = 0.0012),
    metrics=['accuracy'])
```

However, this code doesn't seem to be freezing the first two hidden layers and they are also learning. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Use 'trainable' parameter while defining neural network model to freeze the desired layers of the model as follows-

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(units = 300, activation="relu", kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.GlorotNormal(), trainable = False))

model.add(Dense(units = 100, activation = "relu", kernel_initializer = tf.initializer.GlorotNormal(), trainable = False))

model.add(Dense(units = 10, activation = "softmax"))

# Compile model as usual
```